# Laravel localization, how to get custom language value

Tags: php, laravel, multilingual, laravel-localization

I have **az/app.php, en/app.php and ru/app.php** language files in resources/lang directory, let's say app language is en right know, but I wanna get az language value without changing app language. 
`trans('app.Fransa')` works with current app language so if it is en it gives France, but there is a places in app I need somehow call trans('az.app.fransa') like this, but this way not works

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/localization

Comment: App::setLocale($locale);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
trans('app.Fransa', [], 'az');
```

Comment: Very helpful! How did you know this?